# Automating SSH tunneling on OS X

Tags: macos, ssh, automation, tunnel

I want to automate this SSH tunneling command on OS X.

```
ssh -D port account@server
```

The shell will prompt you to enter the password.

Is it possible to automate it with something like The Automator? any solution is welcomed.

Comment: What part do you want automated?  The whole thing end to end, or do you just not want to be prompted for your password?

Comment: The whole thing. I'm looking for automation that supply the password by itself (yes hard coded).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to automatically create an SSH tunnel is to set up a public/private key pair - that way you can authenticate without a password.

There are some good instructions [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSXServer/Conceptual/XServer_ProgrammingGuide/Articles/SSH.html). It even gives an example of using the SSH connection in a Perl script - although you can use a Bash script or Automator's "Run shell script" action if you'd rather. You can ignore most of the parameters to `ssh-keygen` - it'll prompt you for those that are required.